# How to add the sum of totals in a single mysql table

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following MySQL table:

Site_ID

Serial Number

cost_per_month

cost_per_unit_A

cost_per_unit_B

opening_unit_A

closing_unit_A

opening_unit_B

closing_unit_B

I execute the folowing MySQL query:

```
select 
SITE_ID as 'Site', Serial Number,cost_per_month
cost_per_unit_A, cost_per_unit_B,opening_unit_A, closing_unit_A, opening_unit_B, closing_unit_B
format(cost_per_month+(closing_unit_A-opening_unit_A)*cost_per_unit_A+(closing_unit_B-opening_unit_B)*cost_per_unit_A,2) as 'Total Vat Ex',
format((cost_per_month+(closing_unit_A-opening_unit_A)*cost_per_unit_A+(closing_unit_B-opening_unit_B)*cost_per_unit_A,*0.14,2)) as 'Vat',
format((cost_per_month+(closing_unit_A-opening_unit_A)*cost_per_unit_A+(closing_unit_B-opening_unit_B)*cost_per_unit_A,*1.14,2)) as 'Total Vat inclusive'
where SITE_ID ='Site Name'
```

I would like to change this query so that the totals of the sum of the last addition queries are totaled.

Would I use a group by statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
SITE_ID as 'Site', 
Serial Number,
cost_per_month
cost_per_unit_A, 
cost_per_unit_B,
opening_unit_A,
closing_unit_A, 
opening_unit_B, 
closing_unit_B,
SUM(format(cost_per_month+(closing_unit_A-opening_unit_A)*cost_per_unit_A+(closing_unit_B-opening_unit_B)*cost_per_unit_A,2)) as 'Total Vat Ex',
SUM(format((cost_per_month+(closing_unit_A-opening_unit_A)*cost_per_unit_A+(closing_unit_B-opening_unit_B)*cost_per_unit_A,*0.14,2))) as 'Vat',
SUM(format((cost_per_month+(closing_unit_A-opening_unit_A)*cost_per_unit_A+(closing_unit_B-opening_unit_B)*cost_per_unit_A,*1.14,2))) as 'Total Vat inclusive'
From reading
where SITE_ID ='Site Name'
Group By 
SITE_ID, 
Serial Number,
cost_per_month
cost_per_unit_A, 
cost_per_unit_B,
opening_unit_A,
closing_unit_A, 
opening_unit_B, 
closing_unit_B
```

Comment: The totals for the total vat and total vat inclusive are not being calculated.  Thanks for your input

Comment: I am going to use a php script. i am going load the results into an array and then see.